# Is it possible to use Azure webapp service for hosting a .NET Core webapp as well as a Wordpress platform?

Tags: .net, linux, wordpress, azure, asp.net-core

I have developed a webapp using C# and .NET Core. I can deploy this easily on an Azure webapp service hosting.

I would also like to use Wordpress for some pages, is it possible to host it on the same server?

I would require some URLs to get resolved by the webapp dll, and some others by the Wordpress platform. Again, is that possible?

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I believe it's possible if you use Web App for Containers: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/

Comment: If the URLs are different domain names, YES. If you mean path-based URLs, NO. Note that App Service only runs one OS type (Linux or Window). If your design requires both, then you will need two App Service Plans.

Comment: @JohnHanley I will use only Linux (.Net Core deploys on Linux). Do you mind expanding on why with different domains it would work and not with path-based URLs?

Comment: @ibiza you are asking many questions in one question. Please focus on one problem, and try not to ask "best way" because you will trigger opinions based answer.

Comment: Because using different domains select different services. Using the same domain name but with different paths will go to the service registered for the domain. From there you would have to do an HTTP redirect to get to the other service using path based URLs OR call the other service on behalf of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

An Azure "App Service" (formerly called "Azure Websites") can simultaneously run ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, PHP (WordPress), NodeJS, Java Tomcat, Classic ASP, and FastCGI applications all in the same instance.

Note that to enable multiple Classic ASP and ASP.NET applications to operate side-by-side in the same website you need to set-up Application Scopes (which map a virtual-directory path to a specific application - but the application needs to coded to specifically support operating under a non-default virtual path location). This rule may also apply to ASP.NET Core applications depending on how they're configured and hosted.

You can also make use of IIS's URL rewriting as well which runs before any application code.

Comment: okay thanks! there is no classic ASP involved in my scenario though. Also I think you are speaking with an IIS perspective? I would use a Linux hosting

Comment: @ibiza Ah, you didn't specify that in your question - Azure App Services were exclusively sandboxed IIS application so I assumed you were asking about that. Azure only recently added support for Linux and Docker-based App Services.